# Is passing a bool by value guaranteed to be efficient?

Tags: c++, boolean

If `sizeof(bool) == 1` then passing by value is efficient since `bool` fits in a register (assuming some standard calling convention). However `sizeof(bool)` is implementation defined. So is `bool` always guaranteed to be more efficient when passed by value rather than by reference? Are there any guarantees on upper bounds on `sizeof(bool)`?

Comment: Define "efficient". When you pass the reference, you have to spend the time to dereference it on usage.

Comment: @aryamccarthy Yes, that's what I'm talking about. Passing by value does not involve dereferencing. So its more efficient.

Comment: Why did you use the [tag:c] tag here actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because Because I assume the situation is similar (if not identical) to both C and C++.

Comment: Right—so you have to decide which matters more to you. On Intel, if you have a cache miss, that can be as expensive as a floating point divide. Is that worth the cost of potential space savings when passing params around?

Comment: @aryamccarthy Yes, but if `sizeof(bool)` is for example 1234 bytes, then you have to copy this big structure. And it is no longer efficient. That's what I'm referening to.

Comment: @freakish, @πάνταῥεῖ means that C doesn't have references or a primitive `bool` type. I have already submitted an edit.

Comment: If you are passing bools to functions, there is probably some problem with your design, and I would worry about that rather which is more "efficient", which in the unlikely event it is important to you, you should investigate via benchmarking and profiling.

Comment: @c650 Oh, fair enough. I didn't know that.

Comment: We can all agree that 1234 bytes for a bool is a pretty stupid platform design. I doubt that you'll see something like that in the wild. Beyond that, profiling will tell you how to straddle the tradeoff.

Comment: You're merely asking about the same problem, so it is.

Comment: @freakish They are. Go contemplating! Otherwise _@Baum_ or others could easily decide to reopen that question.

Comment: You can't optimize for a platform that doesn't exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The C++ and C standards are not designed to protect you from maliciously bad implementations.**

Simple as that. You have to trust that your implementation will not *try* to be bad. If it does that, don't use it.

For this specific case: Any implementation that makes copying the built-in integer types expensive would, even if technically conforming, break the performance of tons of real world code and can thus be considered maliciously bad.

So to make the answer explicit: No, it is not guaranteed by the standards because this is outside their scopes. It is, however, guaranteed by real world constraints.

Comment: I'm not worried about it. I'm just curious.

Comment: As I said, you need to trust your implementation. If it *tries* to hurt you, all is lost, here and on other occasions.

Comment: See also [Deathstation 9000](http://www.statemaster.com/encyclopedia/DeathStation-9000)